# An inequality on a matrix involving a norm and the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \left( {a_{ij} } \right)$ be a matrix over $\mathbb R$, of size $n \times n$. Let $\left\{ \lambda _k  \right\}_{k = 1}^n$ be the $n$ eigenvalues of the matrix. Prove the following inequality:

> $$
> \sum_{k = 1}^n \left| {\lambda _k } \right|^2   \leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n \left| {a_{ij} } \right|^2  .
> $$

I can't prove it, and I'm not sure if in the problem one assumes that there exist $n$ real eigenvalues, or it's also true for complex eigenvalues. D:

Comment: I'm fairly certain this follows from Jordan form, for example, and that one has an equality iff $A$ is diagonal over $\mathbf{C}$. Will come back to it if I can...

Comment: Jordan form won't quite work because RHS isn't invariant under general conjugations.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I hesitated writing an answer. Glad someone wrote it out.

Comment: Right hand side is equal to $\operatorname{Tr}(AA^*)$ and trace is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues of the matrix. You might want to continue from there.

Answer (score 3):

This is in fact true even for matrices over $\mathbb{C}$.  Both the left and right side are invariant under conjugating the matrix $A$ by a unitary matrix $Q$.  Therefore by taking the Schur decomposition we can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is upper triangular (but potentially complex even if the original $A$ was real).  Since the eigenvalues of an upper triangular matrix are just the diagonal entries, the inequality follows.

Answer (score 3):

This are [Schur's Inequalities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchursInequalities.html). There are many [proofs](http://books.google.de/books?id=SINcYCWU0rEC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150#v=onepage&q&f=false) that can be found. It basically directly follows from the [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition).